# Trying to return json data with PHP

Tags: php

i want return data from this link
https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd
and my code

```php
$json_url="https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd";
$json=file_get_contents($json_url);
$data=json_decode($json,TRUE);
echo "$"."&nbsp".($data['price']/100);
```

but i see error in line 4 (Unsupported operand types). what is problem?

Comment: Please share the full and exact error message, and your attempts to resolve the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you are looking at does not have a top-level "price" property. It looks like this:

```json
{
  "ticker": {
    "base": "BTC",
    "target": "USD",
    "price": "23167.76928811",
    "volume": "114681.72386308",
    "change": "35.85182665"
  },
  "timestamp": 1608643921,
  "success": true,
  "error": ""
}
```

Maybe you intended to look inside the "ticker" property:

```php
echo "$"."&nbsp".($data['ticker']['price']/100);
```

Comment: thanks . and another question . how can i refresh $data var every x second ?
i want only refresh $data value in page , not all page information refresh.

Comment: That is a different question. The comment section is not really intended for that. But if you don't want to refresh the page, then you should look into a JavaScript solution.